How to create a shared part of view for stack screens?
I have a bar that should be shared between profile/settings and profile/index. In the current configuration, I get a blank screen outside the bar. So I suspect that when defining a nested stack, it shouldn't be wrapped in any parent component? What is the best practice for defining a shared component in a nested Stack that does not need to be re-rendered when changing the page?
I have been thinking about using <Slot/> however I am not sure how to do this in the most appropriate way.
 /(app)
   _layout.tsx
   /profile
      _layout.tsx
      index.tsx
      settings.tsx
   ...

/profile/_layout.tsx:
export default function Profile() {
  return (
    <View position="relative">
      <Bar />
      <Stack
        initialRouteName="profile"
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false
        }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="index" />
        <Stack.Screen name="settings" options={{ animation: 'slide_from_right' }} />
      </Stack>
    </View>
  );
}

const Bar = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Back color="#000" />
    </View>
  );
};

